# Preserving Column Order on Inline Form Inputs with RTL CSS in Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, right-to-left

I have 3 columns in my form for inputting the user's phone:

```
<div class="col-md-5">
     <label class="control-label">Phone</label>
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label for="phone_code" class="sr-only"><fmt:message key="phoneCode"/></label>
            <select class="form-control" name="phoneCode" id="phone_code">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <span class="col-md-2 text-center">-</span>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label for="phone_number" class="sr-only">phone number</label>
            <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="phoneNumber" id="phone_number" dir="LTR" value="${phoneNumber}">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/jgFqaA4r6o

When I include the bootstrap css for rtl:

https://github.com/morteza/bootstrap-rtl

this flips the order of the columns, which in most cases is the desired result. However, I would like the phone input columns to remain in the same order (unaltered).

Including the pull-left class to the first two columns fixes the problem but causes errors when resizing (specifically, shrinking) the screen.
I have tried using/learning the col-**-pull-**/col-**-push-** classes but I couldn't figure out how to make them work here.

Does anybody have any suggestions?
I am also open to changing the general layout if there are improvements on that as well.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the html and used a small "hack" to solve this.
There is still probably a better solution out there. This is my html:

```
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 pull-left">
            <label for="phone_code" class="control-label">phone code</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
            <label for="phone_number" class="control-label">phone number</label>
            <input type="tel" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/tIW6xBHVGB

The "hack" is the "`col-xs-12`" class added to the `<div>` elements. If not added, the divs don't expand to take up the entire row as they should due to the "`pull-left`" class.

I'm open to hearing other suggestions.